# Multiple Google api keys in manifest file (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, api-key

I am trying to add two api keys i.e Google places api key and google maps api key.
But I am not able to add both at same time to manifest file.How can I achieve the same.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

The error I am getting is

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

I am including api keys like this

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxx"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the manifest.

Comment: post your manifest @Amit Nair

Comment: I have edited my question..is it enough?

Comment: But that I need for displaying maps in my application @Bajirao

Comment: android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" this is sufficient for it

Comment: remove `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxx"/>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177486/getting-error-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-in-my-app

Comment: @AmitNair see my answer bellow

Comment: @AmitNair Did you fix yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes....:)..I removed api key for google maps..Now I am able to access get both google places and google maps..:)

Comment: @AmitNair Move ahead .

Comment: I am facining similar problem using fcm and google map please check here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47585798/5459156

Answer (score 2):

Use following meta-data in your manifest. there is no need to create another api key for places api if you already have  api key for google map.
If you are using both Maps & Places Api in your application then you only need to specify geo api key.and just enable Places Api.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Whats your Error log saying**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be
>   specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with
>   the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml

Just remove

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="xxxx"/>
```

Make sure you have below permissions . **Enough for Map Showing** .

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/common_google_api_key" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
```

Read

> [Getting error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity" in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177486/getting-error-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-in-my-app)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding two different API keys, for the same project enable both keys and copy down the same key as follows for single project which you want currently

```
<!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaS******************WDaKCEHP" />    

<!-- Google Places API Key -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaS******************WDaKCEHP" />
```