# Use both Google Places and Maps api android application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, metadata, google-places-api

I am using Google Maps and Google Places in the same android application.

For that, If I am defining 2 meta tags in manifest,

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/places_api" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/places_api"/>
```

then it through me the exception,

**The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the `<application>` element of AndroidManifest.xml**

and if I remove one meta-tag, according functionality stops working.

I refered  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028760/multiple-google-api-keys-in-manifest-file-android/36028944) link, but no success.
How Can I resolve this issue ?
Thanks in advance folks.

Comment: Try with small letters "com.google.android.geo.api_key"

Comment: @NaveenKumarM
wow..Its working man..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) and [Google Maps Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-key) you will see that both require the same meta tag:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

So you need only one meta tag and shared API key to use these APIs together.